# Find and Replace Column value from Over all Database

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a query to find out one column value on overall tables of database and need to replace that

eg: from below screenshot,both tables contains the column 'CompanyID' contains 36 digit char,i need to find out the same char from whole database and replace with other 36 digit char

.[image]

Comment: We're keen to help, the keyword being help - not do it all for you. So show us what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: Make it easy, and possible to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: [Why not to use images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

I saw this somewhere I tried it and it worked. You can give it a go

```
DECLARE @stringToFind VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @stringToReplace VARCHAR(100) 
DECLARE @schema sysname 
DECLARE @table sysname 
DECLARE @count INT 
DECLARE @sqlCommand VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @where VARCHAR(8000) 
DECLARE @columnName sysname 
DECLARE @object_id INT 

SET @stringToFind = 'Apple' ---- what you want to replace
SET @stringToReplace = 'mango' ---- what you want to replace it with

DECLARE TAB_CURSOR CURSOR  FOR 
SELECT   B.NAME      AS SCHEMANAME, 
         A.NAME      AS TABLENAME, 
         A.OBJECT_ID 
FROM     sys.objects A 
         INNER JOIN sys.schemas B 
           ON A.SCHEMA_ID = B.SCHEMA_ID 
WHERE    TYPE = 'U' 
ORDER BY 1 

OPEN TAB_CURSOR 

FETCH NEXT FROM TAB_CURSOR 
INTO @schema, 
     @table, 
     @object_id 

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
  BEGIN 
    DECLARE COL_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT A.NAME 
    FROM   sys.columns A 
           INNER JOIN sys.types B 
             ON A.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID = B.SYSTEM_TYPE_ID 
    WHERE  OBJECT_ID = @object_id 
           AND IS_COMPUTED = 0 
           AND B.NAME IN ('char','nchar','nvarchar','varchar','text','ntext') 

    OPEN COL_CURSOR 

    FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR 
    INTO @columnName 

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
      BEGIN 
        SET @sqlCommand = 'UPDATE ' + @schema + '.' + @table + ' SET [' + @columnName 
                           + '] = REPLACE(convert(nvarchar(max),[' + @columnName + ']),''' 
                           + @stringToFind + ''',''' + @stringToReplace + ''')' 

        SET @where = ' WHERE [' + @columnName + '] LIKE ''%' + @stringToFind + '%''' 

        EXEC( @sqlCommand + @where) 

        SET @count = @@ROWCOUNT 

        IF @count > 0 
          BEGIN 
            PRINT @sqlCommand + @where 
            PRINT 'Updated: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@count) 
            PRINT '----------------------------------------------------' 
          END 

        FETCH NEXT FROM COL_CURSOR 
        INTO @columnName 
      END 

    CLOSE COL_CURSOR 
    DEALLOCATE COL_CURSOR 

    FETCH NEXT FROM TAB_CURSOR 
    INTO @schema, 
         @table, 
         @object_id 
  END 

CLOSE TAB_CURSOR 
DEALLOCATE TAB_CURSOR
```